How to identify the attribute and dunder method in python object since they both start with double underscore?
I am getting hard time in distinguishing between the identification of an attribute and dunder method that is related to  object.
see example below.
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "sahil"
        self.age = 32

    def foo(self):
        print("in foo method")

t1 = Test()
print(dir(t1))

output:

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'age', 'foo', 'name']

since __dict__ is an attribute while others are dunder method. How would i identify since starts with double underscore?

What you are looking at are dunder attributes and dunder methods, what exactly is your question? If you are trying to find out whether the attribute is callable or not just use the builtin callable on the attributes you are interested in.

Methods are merely attributes which are functions. So you'll want to test values for what kind of value they are. The names of those values won't help there.

@metatoaster, there must be a distinction in the name itself if it is a method or an attribute. By using any other function, I can certainly find out.

Your assertion that "there must be a distinction in the name itself if it is a method or an attribute" is not documented anywhere. The name itself does not say anything about whether it's callable or not, there may be documentation about what specific dunder attributes should be callable, but there is no system or rules in place that you can tell that an arbitrary identifier must point to something that must be callable.

You can use a combination of callable and getattr to check the details. Methods itself will come in gettattr and that's why you have to check if they are callable's.
print([(a, 'function' if callable(getattr(t1, a)) else 'attribute') for a in dir(t1)])


The only thing this won't tell you is whether a function is specifically a member function.  You could assign any old random function to a variable.
